# Blender won't start, while I used it before on this machine

Tags: installation

I updated my laptop. It is an old one, but I used blender before on this machine.

I liked it a lot.

Now I want to reinstall it (did a full hd format) and this happens

[image: Now I want to reinstall it (did a full hd format) and this happens]

Please help.

Also,

I want to use blender to make svg for usage in html.
How can it be done?

(design a logo)

thank you for reading,

J.L.

downloaded latest version of blender 1 hour ago

Comment: Hey @Smart prime6! Welcome to blender.stackexchange.com! I suggest you take a look at the site [Tour](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour) for the basics, also, in the future make sure to ask 1 question per post, we encourage you to make as many posts for as many questions as you desire.

Comment: Make sure you reinstalled all your system's graphic drivers after the format, and make sure your GPU is capable of supporting the required OpenGL version

Answer (score 2):

Blender recently **switched to opengl 2.1** so you will need to **upgrade your hardware** to support opengl 2.1 or switch to an **older Blender version**. The last version to support older versions of opengl is blender 2.76.

You can find a note about that in the release notes of Blender 2.77
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.77

Comment: I used blender about 2 years ago. Back them I build a submarine ,scaled at about the real size, for as far as I could remember being a mechanic/electrician on an actual military sub for years. And I remember almost every bolt and knob. It was a pretty large file by the way. The cool part was, that I modeled it in 3D and let it sail in the harbor and submerge at open sea. So, you could say I did know how to have fun with Blender. But it was this hardware. Now it does not start and I did try to update everything. I should have the latest available drivers in use. Could it be a Win10 thing?

Comment: I can only repeat the answer: download a version before blender 2.77 and it will work:http://download.blender.org/release/

Comment: I downloaded 2.77 and it works. Still I get a error message, but can also use the app (?). Thank you very much for this.